# Regex to match a section in a piece of text

Tags: c#, regex, text

I've been pondering over this for hours now and I've not come up with a working regular expression :(

I have paragraphs of text, some of the lines are section headings and these are what I want to match.

Each section begins with a number, the number could be 1 or 1.1 or 1.1.1 or 1.1.1.1 etc. 
And after one or more whitespaces or tabs the section title begins and ends with a CR or LF.

For example

3.4.1 Section about how regular expressions are built.

I need to match string like the one above in a body of plain text.

Any pointers would be highly appreciated. :) Thx!

Comment: Give us some of your examples, maybe the can be corrected.

Comment: This is what I have so far:
\d\.\d\.\d\s+\w+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an expression like this to match such lines:

```
(?m)^\d+(?:\.\d+)*[ \t]+\S.*$
```

Explained and tested at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/pY1iL0)

Answer (score 2):

A few digits followed by a few groups of dot preceded few digits

```
\d+(\.\d+)+
```